# React admin `AutocompleteArrayInput` shows [object, Object]

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When using a Custom component as the optionText for AutocompleteInput, I see the `[object, Object]` rather than expecting data. (You can see the current result below)

I expect to see the `Avatar` and `Username` on the list, however the children component doesn't work

And also when clicking a item, it said `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'record')`

But when I do console log the `choice` prop in option text, the data is existed.

The code snippet is :

```
  return (
  <ReferenceInput
    source={source}
    label={label}
    reference="users"
    filterToQuery={filterToQuery(isDriver)}
    {...props}
  >
    <AutocompleteInput
      {...autocompleteDefaultOptions}
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
      resettable
    />
  </ReferenceInput>
);
```

and the options is this :

```
const autocompleteDefaultOptions: Partial<AutocompleteInputProps> = {
  optionText: (choice?) => {
    if (!choice?.id) {
      return 'Not thing in the list.';
    }
    return <CustomOptionTextField />;
  },
  inputText: (choice) => choice?.name || '',
  matchSuggestion: (_: string, choice) => Boolean(choice?.name),
};
```

The custom component is this :

```
export const CustomOptionTextField = ({
  record,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  if (!record){
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <UserAvatar
        user={record}
        className={classes.avatar}
      />
      <Typography variant="body2" component="span">
        {record?.name || 'Anonyme'}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Below image is the current situation :
[image]

And this is the data I see, when I do console.log for choice :

[image]

Dose anyone can help this out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The docs indicate that if you intend to use a function that returns a component, you should instead use the inputText prop and follows up with an example of such. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#autocompleteinput

Comment: Maybe it is because you pass "optionText" props a function that returns "string | OptionTextElement". It may be buggy because not many persons use it.

I usually prefer to directly return a OptionTextElement with the JSX syntax.

Answer (score -1):

It might be irrelevant but you don't pass a `record` prop in:

```
return <CustomOptionTextField />;
```

Also from the last image it's not clear whether there is a name property on choice, and if it's a string or an object.

Comment: As you can see the last component snippet I wrote, the record is automatically passed in react admin, if the component is child of ‘ReferenceInput’ but thanks for commenting anyway!